Extend Class Issue - Laravel
I created an extend of the class that manages HTTPV1 firebase notifications, it is a package installed via composer.
Original Class:
Extendend Class
namespace App\Notifications;

use App\Models\Order;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Appy\FcmHttpV1\FcmNotification;

class NewAssignedOrderRestaurant extends FcmNotification
{
    protected $order;

    /** 
     * Imposta l'ordine.
     * @param Order $order
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setOrder(Order $order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Override del metodo prepareSend per personalizzare la logica di preparazione dei dati.
     */
    protected function prepareSend()
    {
        $data = [
            "orderID" => $this->order->id ?? null,
            "id" => 'orders',
            "status" => $this->order->order_status_id ?? null,
            "active" => $this->order->active ?? null,
        ];

        $message = [
            "title" => $this->title,
            "body" => $this->body,
            "icon" => $this->icon != null ? asset($this->icon) : '',
            "click_action" => $this->click_action ?? ''
        ];

        if (isset($this->topic)) {
            $payload = [
                "message" => [
                    "topic" => $this->topic,
                    "notification" => $message,
                    "data" => $data,
                ],
            ];
        } elseif (isset($this->token)) {
            $payload = [
                "message" => [
                    "token" => $this->token,
                    "notification" => $message,
                    "data" => $data,
                ],
            ];
        }

        $encodedData = json_encode($payload);
            
        return $this->handleSend($encodedData);
    }
}

The problem is that even though I am modifying the contents of prepareSend by changing the structure and adding customData, the system continues to use the function present in the composer file and does not extend.
This is the part where I instantiate the class and send the notification.
use App\Notifications\NewAssignedOrderRestaurant;

$notification = new NewAssignedOrderRestaurant();
$notification->setOrder($order);
$notification->setTitle('Order Update');
$notification->setBody('Your order has been updated.');
$notification->setToken('your-fcm-token');
$response = $notification->send();

The notification is sent, but respecting the contents of the original class.
I also tried putting a print log inside the extend class, but nothing cares.
Any advice? It's very strange.
Thanks!

since the send method is being called from the parent class, $this->prepareSend within send will also reference the parent method

@krisgjika Thanks, how can I make the override work? it's strange, it's never happened to me.

you need to overwrite the send method also

@krisgjika right. the original class is private lol, i thought it was protected :D i need to sleep. thanks dear.
